Relative running times of equivalent Turing machines with arbitrary and binary alphabets
Cross posted from CS Stackexchange as no answers were found there. If it is found inappropriate for this site I will remove it.
The book "Computational Complexity: A modern approach" by Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak contains the following claim:

Claim 1.5 For every $f : \{0, 1\}^∗ \to \{0, 1\}$ and time-constructible $T : N \to N$, if $f$ is computable in time $T(n)$ by a TM $M$ using alphabet , then it is computable in time $4\log|\Gamma|T(n)$ by a TM $\tilde{M̃}$ using the alphabet $\{0, 1,\square,\rhd \}$.

(TM denotes "Turing Machine and the characters $\square$ and $\rhd$ are used to denote blanks and the starting cell of the TM's tape respectively)
What I don't understand is the factor of $4$ that appears in the running time of $\tilde{M}$. The idea of the proof is that the elements of $\Gamma$ can be encoded in $\log|\Gamma|$ bits and $\tilde M$ can be designed to read and write $\log|\Gamma|$ cells at a time. So to simulate one step of $M$ $\tilde M$ would use $\log|\Gamma|$ steps to read the encoding of a single element of $\Gamma$ and $\log|\Gamma|$ more to write one on it's tape. Wouldn't this make the running time of $\tilde M$ $2\log|\Gamma|T(n)$ as opposed to $4\log|\Gamma|T(n)$?
Any help resolving this problem is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!
